# How to display the field history related list for a custom object on a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, related-list

I cannot find anything equivalent to:

```
<apex:relatedList list="ProcessSteps" />
```

which works for Approvals.

The only solution I can think of is to build a controller/extension that gets the raw history data (from MyObj__History) and write my own page elements to render it in a table. Is there a neater solution?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a simple solution by just utilizing apex:relatedList. The way I have done it has always been a custom solution.

I would check out [this link](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/History-related-List-using-Visualforce/td-p/151785) for more information on how to do it with a custom component.

Answer (score 3):

> Spring '17 (API v39.0)

The `Histories` relationship works for custom objects: `<apex:relatedList list="Histories"/>`.

I couldn't find it mentioned in the release notes. Thanks for forum user sgkmills for [pointing it out](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000095wwIAA).

Answer (score 2):

I agree, I believe you need to create your own History Related List in VF.  [Iterative Logic has created a good article](http://www.iterativelogic.com/create-your-own-history-related-list-in-visualforce/) that details how to create a History Related List of your own.