# Display Opportunity field history Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, related-list

I am new to Salesforce development and trying to resolve an issue i have come across. Any inputs are highly Appreciated.

I have developed a `custom visual force page` for the `Opportunity details` and i want to display a `Opportunity Field History` Related list. I used the Following Apex tag to display the code, but Its showing " `Histories` is not a valid child relationship name for entity Opportunity". Can you please let me know what the issue is?

```
 <apex:relatedlist list="OpportunityTeamMembers" title="Opportunity Team"/>
 <apex:relatedlist list="Histories" title="Opportunity Team"/>
 <apex:relatedlist list="OpportunityHistories" title="Stage History"/>
 <apex:relatedlist list="Contracts__r" title="Contracts"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: could be tagged as duplicate for : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/how-to-display-the-field-history-related-list-for-a-custom-object-on-a-visualfor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Histories is a special related list you need to build it using  or  or

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity">
 <apex:relatedlist list="OpportunityHistories" title="Stage History"/>
 <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:pageblocktable value="{!opportunity.Histories}" var="hist" title="opporty">
 <apex:column value="{!hist.createddate}"/>
 </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this Is working perfectly. made my day. Since morning trying to figure out how to solve this :)

Comment: Does this work for Assets as well?