# how to show lead history in related in vf page

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I want show lead history in vf page. I tried as below

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!Lead}" list="LeadHistory"/>
```

and

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!Lead}" list="Histories"/>
```

but page show error "not a child relation ship"

Comment: If possible please include the screen shot of error as well for getting a better understanding

Comment: 'Histories' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Lead

This is the Error

Comment: History objects are not supported in relatedList component.

Comment: lead History showing in  detail page of lead record

Answer (score 0):

You can not able to display History data using `<apex:relatedList>` component.

[How to display History related list using <apex:relatedList> or by any other direct approach on a Visualforce page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50285/how-to-display-history-related-list-using-apexrelatedlist-or-by-any-other-dir)

Refer one helpful [blog](http://www.iterativelogic.com/create-your-own-history-related-list-in-visualforce/) to create History component using apex